Leaflet draw polyline on train tracks
im trying to creating polyline between points in leaflet.
Im trying use Routing but it work only for roads(i need on train tracks).
Did you have any ideas what i can try next?
Im trying to use Routing, but only works on roads
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'});
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());    

L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: latlngs,
}).addTo(map);  


Did you ever find a good way to do this? I have a similar project and would love to explore a solution.
